# I am getting 401 and 419 error in view results tree while testing my web application in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, testng

Thread Name:Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start:2022-07-07 21:49:33 IST
Load time:815
Connect Time:0
Latency:815
Size in bytes:8118
Sent bytes:1831
Headers size in bytes:1483
Body size in bytes:6635
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:419
Response message:

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html; charset=UTF-8
DataEncoding: UTF-8

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. [HTTP Status 401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) means `Unauthorized`
2. HTTP Status 419 is not in the [standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231.html#section-6.1) so it's something custom. If you're trying to test an application built on [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) it means that you don't properly handle [CSRF tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/csrf).

The solution for both is [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start). When it comes to modern web applications it's not possible to just replay the recorded script because they rely on many dynamic parameters starting from [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) and ending with CSRF tokens. The latter ones need to be handled manually like it's described in JMeter Regular Expression Extractor: [How to Extract Tokens and Session IDs to Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-regular-expressions-extractor) article